# NetSuite and Shopify Integration

Tags: shopify, netsuite

Hi I am trying to integrate NetSuite and Shopify, I am facing an issue in Shopify webhook, I have given Suitelet's external url in Shopify webhook but this link is not working, I tried with requestbin its working fine.
Is there any issue with Suitelets external url.
Please help.

Answer (score -1):

What you are likely running into is that Suitelets are set up to be used from a client side script. This behaviour existed for years and then disappeared for a while then it showed up again in 2017.1. The behaviour is that if the inbound suitelet call doesn't have a recognized user-agent header Netsuite drops the call.

I do a lot of Netsuite and developed a proxy for suitelet calls that handles this but that is something I apply sparingly and on a client-by-client basis.

The other issue you'll run into is request throttling back to Shopify. This is difficult to deal with from Netsuite since their server side http methods are all synchronous so you'd have to get clever (first thing I'd investigate if you are intent on this is with scheduled scripts that send updates to Shopify until you are about to run out of api calls and then re-schedule themselves)

FWIW I have a [Netsuite-to-Shopify](https://www.knightsofthenet.com/shopify.html) connector already in production. If you are trying to connect your Netsuite account to Shopify I'd recommend looking at that.

FarApp and Celigo also offer Netsuite to Shopify though I believe theirs are more expensive than mine.